# New Edge Update Silent Kiosk Printing Problem

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode, ticket-system

For some time I've already had set up and running the silent kiosk printing mode for ticket printing on an Edge Shortcut by appending "--kiosk-printing". It worked until today's Edge update (version 94.0.992.31).

First I thought it was the update and I tried silent printing on Chrome and other Chromium based browsers without changing anything else, and worked.

Then after some time, back on Edge I tried printing a page from https://printatestpage.com and it got printed alright.

So I got confused, then tried to print my ticket again but still couldn't print.

Then I thought that maybe the markup isn't properly written, but it was ok when I passed it through w3c validator.

So I tried printing small chunks of the html ticket and it did print each chunk, except for one that contained a table element (I was printing via console "window.print();" and on the other chunks it returned "undefined" back but when I got to the table, it didn't returned anything which meant that it got "stuck" printing).

So, **TL;DR**; silent printing on the new Edge update doesn't work whenever there's a table element inside the html.

Of course I can change the markup and try to not use a table element anymore, but I'm looking if there's anyone else with this kind of problem, plus maybe I can help someone with all the things I did to troubleshoot.

Comment: You mean the problem is mainly related to the printing of table elements? I am not sure how to reproduce your problem, and printing problems may be tricky, you can refer to [this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/troubleshoot-print-issues-in-microsoft-edge-639b1bf9-49a7-4d86-8d98-0617b61034fa) appropriately, it may be helpful to you.